# How can I display a twitter feed In Android programmatically?

Tags: android, twitter

How can I display a twitter feed In Android programmatically?

Comment: You should look into using [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) [Here's a tutorial I found by doing  a quick google search.](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please be more specific of what you want to do (maybe what your motivation is), what you know/tried already and where exactly you are stuck. It makes answering your questions easier.

Having said that, I see two main aspects of what your app should do:

1. Fetch the tweets for a given feed
2. Displaying them

I guess how building Android apps and user interfaces works is something you already know to some extend (if not this is a separate question).

So what is missing is a way to communicate with the twitter server and retrieve the tweets. For tasks like that (not only twitter) there are usually APIs defined and you can find libraries to do most of the hard work for you.

In this case a web search for "twitter api android" leads you to twitter's [list of available Twitter libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries), sorted by language. Android programming is usually done in Java. In the list you find three Java libraries to choose from, with one explicitly mentioned as Android compatible: [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org) (under Apache license).

Have fun playing around with that one. The section "code examples" might be worth a look as well.

Edit: [Twitter API ME](http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/pages/Home) is also android compatible (and GPL / LGPL licensed). And there is [TwAPIme](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twapime.app), an app demonstrating its features, with source code available (for download link and license see end of description in Google Play).

Comment: Thanks well i know android by 6th month of exprience,,and ya i want to fetch tweets feed in my android list view

Comment: Oh and Twitter API me also looks interesting. They have an example app. I have added it to the answer.